# How to create a batch file on Windows to write out strings from a text file based on a substring and new line?

Tags: batch-file, grep, findstr

folks!

I'm not sure if this is a very simple task or a very complicated one, but either way I'm struggling with it. Suppose I have a text file like this:

```
11111FOO
11111BAR
22222ZOOM
33333FOO
11111CAR
```

I want to figure out a command line in windows that I can plop into a batch file that will pull out text strings from this file and push them to a new file. I would pass in the leading string to search for, and it would take everything from the end of that string to the next new line.

So using the above example, if I said the leading string was 11111, I would get a new text file that looked like this:

```
FOO
BAR
CAR
```

Everything else would be ignored.

Thanks!

Comment: are these always numbers?Are the numbers at the fromt with fixed length?

Comment: Using [JREPL.BAT - a pure script regular expression command line text processor](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044): `call jrepl "^11111" "" /a /f "input.txt" /o "output.txt"`.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no potential poison characters in the input file then perhaps this would suffice:

```bat
@(For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("input.txt") Do @(Set "an=%%A"
    For /L %%B In (%%A 1 %%A) Do @Call Echo %%an:*%%B=%%))>"output.txt"
```

---

Magoo's additions:

```bat
@Echo Off
(For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("q46858215.txt") Do (Set "an=%%A"
    For /L %%B In (%%A 1 %%A) Do Call Echo %%an:*%%B=%%))>"Output1.txt"

If "%~1"=="" GoTo :Next
(For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr/BLC:"%~1" "q46858215.txt"') Do (
    Set "an=%%A"
    For /L %%B In (%%A 1 %%A) Do Call Echo %%an:*%%B=%%))>"Output2.txt"

:Next
(For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("q46858215.txt") Do (Set "an=%%A"
    For /L %%B In (%%A 1 %%A) Do Echo %%B))>"Output3.txt"
```

I used a file named `q46858215.txt` containing OP's data for my testing.

Produces three output files:

Output1.txt : Compo's original
Output2.txt : filtered to isolate lines beginning with *(first parameter to routine)*
Output3.txt : Compo's original in reverse, showing the numbers isolated

Comment: Interesting approach - a general-purpose 'remove leading numeric string' snippet. Problem is that it doesn't filter on OP's required "11111" (someone fixed that) and it's obviously limited to 9 practical digits. Still, good thinking nevertheless. I've included the obvious reverse (extract leading digit-strings) for completion - and that has the problem that it will generate `0` for lines with *no* leading digits.

Comment: Your answer assumes there are no digits within the desired result. Not a good assumption. But if the assumption is valid, then a much faster robust solution is as simple as `(for /f "delims=0123456789" %%A in ('findstr /r "^11111[^0123456789]" "input.txt"') do echo %%A) >"output.txt"`